# Code memory used for calling a function (C ARM-GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, memory

I have written a C program for a 32-bits ARM core micro-controller project. The project has a LCD so I have written a function for loading text to the LCD's internal RAM for display, the function is:

```
/*-------------------------------------------
* Name       :  LCD_Show_String
* Description  :  Load a line of text to LCD's RAM
* Argument(s) :  row - load to which row in LCD.
*                *str - The text
*                *font_table - the font table to be used
*                *font_descriptor - information of the font table
*                align - Align ALIGN_LEFT, ALIGN_CENTER or ALIGN_RIGHT
*                print_now - 0: Do not print the text on LCD now
*                            1: Print the text on LCD immediately
*                mode - PIXEL_ON, PIXEL_OFF or PIXEL_XOR (method to print each pixel) 
*
* Return value: Total width of the string printed.
* -----------------------------------------------*/
UINT16_T LCD_Show_String(UINT8_T row, const UINT8_T *str, const UINT8_T *font_table, \
                const UINT16_T *font_descriptor, LCD_Align_t align,
                UINT8_T print_now, LcdPixelMode mode)
```

When I call this function:

```
LCD_Show_String( 7, "TEST", small_font_bitmap,
                        small_font_des, ALIGN_CENTER, 0, PIXEL_ON );
```

I found that each time I call this function, it used up 40 bytes of code memory. Also if I increase the number of parameter in the function, the memory needed will be more. For example originally I have 13 parameters in this functions, it used up to about 100 bytes each time I called this function.

I would like to ask is it normal? Why it used up so many memory? Can I reduce the memory used?

The compiler is ARM GCC compiler

Thank you.

Comment: How much RAM does your MCU have?

Comment: Well it has 16KB RAM, but I am talking about the program memory, not the RAM. It has 256KB memory, but I am almost used it up.

Comment: did you try compiling in `-Os` mode?

Comment: The IDE seems cannot set the optimization level. In fact I have tried to use Keil compiler instead of the IDE's GCC compiler, it does reduced the code size for 30%...

Comment: it should have some places to set the options, you just have to dig out or read the manual

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function so you are creating a stack frame.  You have R0~R15, so that's 16 registers.  If you are in thumb mode, at 16-bits each, that gives you 32 bytes plus the return address, and the state, so I would say that would give you the 40bytes.  I see no way to decrease this.  You could inline the function.  40 bytes really isn't anything on an ARM.

Comment: My ARM has 256KB code memory, however as this project has quite a lot functions, and it has many different screens for the user interface, I have used up all 256KB. This functions may be called several hundreds times. Previously as I used up the memory, I found that if I reduce the number of parameters in this function, it could reduce the total code size for about 20KB. Please be reminded that I am not talking about the RAM, I am talking about program memory.

Comment: @eepty It takes the same in memory as program code memory because you need to "PUSH" every register onto the stack.  If you want to hazard assembly, you could just inline the code or if you know you are using a subset of the registers, you could push only a few variables.  I've pushed only the return address, and 3 registers to the stack before because I knew the rest were garbage, but that's a risky path.  It also makes your code difficult to manage.